# RegEx for PHP preg_replace swapping matches and matching multiple instances

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm looking for a RegEx for preg_replace in PHP for the following scenario:

- example string `"Bjerre- Jonas, Jorgensen- Silas, Wohlert- Johan, Madsen- Bo"`
- desired string `"Jonas Bjerre, Silas Jorgensen, Johan Wohlert, Bo Madsen"`
- string is a csv field and double quotes are enclosures and are part of string
- any number of occurrences may exist including none - the example clearly has 4
- there is a consistent `-` to match on separating matches to be swapped

I'm a noob at PHP and RegEx and have been playing around in the cool [test arena](http://www.phpliveregex.com/) with things like `preg_replace("/^\"(?<=- )/", ""$2 $1$3"", $input_lines);` with horrible results.  Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
([^," -]*)\s*-\s*([^," ]*)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hI0qP0/20

```
$re = "/([^\", -]*)\\s*-\\s*([^,\" ]*)/m"; 
$str = "\"Bjerre- Jonas, Jorgensen- Silas, Wohlert- Johan, Madsen- Bo\""; 
$subst = "$2 $1"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: Thanks, vks! It complains if I use 'g' modifier per demo but seems to work fine without any modifiers at all.

Comment: @BartmanEH `g is implicit with preg_replace(), you don't need to include it.`

Comment: I added a space after the dash to match only the unique case of '- ' as follows: `/([^", - ]*)\s*-\s*([^," ]*)/` and now it works for the following string with hyphenated lastname: `"Reisle- Martin, Malinowski- Jay, Brant-Briscall- Aiden, Vaughan- Elliot, Dolmont- Mark"` returning `"Martin Reisle, Jay Malinowski, Aiden Brant-Briscall, Elliot Vaughan, Mark Dolmont"`

Comment: @BartmanEH that is incorrect.` - ` inside `[]` forms an incorrect range.Use https://regex101.com/r/hI0qP0/24 instead.

Comment: @BartmanEH your regex was same as `([^", ]*)\s*-\s*([^," ]*)` `first group did not match -`

Comment: Thanks again vks. I was reviewing regex101.com's explanation of how it worked and couldn't understand how my error with an incorrect range worked at all but that's the way it goes with RegEx - you can get remarkably good accidental results in some test cases but the error will be exposed in subsequent test cases or in production

Comment: I'm curious if the RegEx could be tweaked to accommodate the following case: `"Clayton- Adam, The Edge, Bono, Mullen- Larry- Jr, Brant-Briscall- Aiden"` to yield `"Adam Clayton, The Edge, Bono, Larry-Mullen Jr, Aiden Brant-Briscall"` without the space between `Larry-` and `Mullen` since it now returns `"Adam Clayton, The Edge, Bono, Larry- Mullen Jr, Aiden Brant-Briscall"`?

Comment: @BartmanEH it would coz problems to others strings.Its tough bringing out this change :(